# Why is the rubberized paste around wiring?

Tags: electrical, wiring

Looking at our crawl space, in places where wires run through the wood framing/2x4s there is a rubberized red glue/adhesive smeared around the wire. Means that wire can't pull through or move, essentially glued at the hole.

Any idea why this is done? Is this necessary?

For context: house is less than 10 years old.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is fire stop caulk. It prevents flames from traveling up inside the walls. If you make any holes in an area that has fire stop, you should also fill those holes with fire stop.

Comment: In this particular case I’m not sure what it is stopping though. Overzealous assistant perhaps.

Comment: It's prepared for possible drywall finish, which has not yet and may never happen, and keeps the inspector happy. So it's stopping the electrical from failing inspection.

Comment: It's stopping flame and smoke travel between the wall cavity and the floor system above (where there may eventually be a drywall barrier between). this is a critical measure to reduce fire transmission, giving you time to escape.

Comment: @JonCuster It was an easy target for the inspector to harp on when the electrician was all done; easily and hastily fixed. It's easy prey so that the inspector doesn't harp on other things that would take more time to fix.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus [Obligatory.](https://dilbert.com/strip/1997-07-12)

Comment: I imagine it also functions as a bit of strain relief, not that it particularly needs it.